# How to call one initializer from another in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, constructor, initializer

How to DRY the following code and call the first initializer from the second?

```
class DataStream

  attr_reader :asset
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(asset)
    @asset = asset
    @data = Array.new
  end

  def initialize(asset, values)
    @asset = asset
    @data = Array.new
    values.each do |value|
      add_value(value)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: In future, can you put an `end` at the end so that we can copy and paste your example into IRB as-is? Also, it's easier to read your code if you indent it normally (two spaces before `attr_reader` and `def`, and only two extra spaces within the `each` block). http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128558/38765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use default arguments:

```
def initialize(asset, values = [])
  @asset = asset
  @data = Array.new
  values.each do |value|
    add_value(value)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't define two method with same name, if you did, only the last one take place, something like redefined the method.

You could use optional parameter like:

```
def initialize(asset, values = nil)
    @asset = asset
    @data = Array.new
    values.each do |value|
        add_value(value)
    end if values
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
class DataStream
  attr_reader :asset
  attr_reader :data
  def initialize(asset, values=nil)
    @asset=asset
    @data = Array.new
    values.each{|v| add_value(v)} unless values.nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use warnings, Ruby will tell you redefined an existing method, and therefore can't use it any more:

```
$VERBOSE = true
class DataStream

  attr_reader :asset
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(asset)
    @asset = asset
    @data = Array.new
  end

  def initialize(asset, values)
    @asset = asset
    @data = Array.new
    values.each do |value|
      add_value(value)
    end
  end
end
```

gives

```
(irb):12: warning: method redefined; discarding old initialize
(irb):7: warning: previous definition of initialize was here
```